# Проверка вхождения пользователя в группу Active Directory

Tags: .net, powershell, active-directory

Дано:
Есть ноутбук подключающийся к корпоративной сети при помощи VPN, на ноутбуке установлен  Cisco AnyConnect Start Before Login Module, т.е. пользователь авторизуется непосредственно в домене, а не использует кэшированную запись. Хотя на другом ноуте, работает даже с кэшированной записью и без VPN.
При попытке проверить вхождение пользователя в любой группе выдаёт ошибку:

> Исключение при вызове "IsInRole" с "1" аргументами: "Не удалось
> установить доверительные отношения между этой рабочей станцией и
> основным доменом."

для проверки используется команда powershell

```
[Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal]::new(
[System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()
).isinrole('Domain Users')
```

**Test-ComputerSecureChannel** показывает что с трастами полный порядок

**Get-WMIObject Win32_ComputerSystem** и **$env:LOGONSERVER** показывают верную информацию

на домен контроллере *lastlogon* и для пользователя и для компьютера свежие

как-то идеи закончились, может кто пнёт в нужном направлении?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всем спасибо, проблема оказалась на уровне межсетевых экранов